# How to speed up ffmpeg streaming on android using libvlc?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, vlc, live-streaming, libvlc

I'm streaming live from my GoPro inside my android app. I use ffmpeg to receive the streaming data from the GoPro and vlc to play it in a surfaceview. I used the code which is provided by KonradIT [here](https://github.com/KonradIT/gopro-udp-stream-android). The main command used for the ffmpeg is:

```
-fflags nobuffer -f mpegts -i udp://:8554 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:8555/gopro?pkt_size=64
```

and the options for vlclib are:

```
options.add("--aout=opensles");
options.add("--audio-time-stretch");
options.add("-vvv");
```

The output is something worse. It's laggy and its speed is about 17 FPS. And one annoying thing is the streamed picture is very small and as far as I tried, there was no way to make it larger and stretched.
I want to know if there is any command to speedup the streaming (in anyway, even by reducing the quality) ? Either on the side of ffmpeg or vlc.

Comment: Are you using ffmpeg to do the relay of packets or transcoding the mpegts packets or transformating the mpegts packets ( changing the packet size ).

Comment: As far as I know we receive mpeg and send mpeg and it acts like a virtual port or gate that the player use to understand the stream. So, I think it seems to do the relay of packets. I'm not sure (because there's no official explanation from GoPro and these all are unofficial)

Answer (score 0):

If it is only doing a relay of packets, try this :

```
ffmpeg -fflags nobuffer -f mpegts -i udp://:8554 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts  udp://127.0.0.1:8555/gopro?pkt_size=1316
```

You can play with different packet sizes based on the MTU size of your network (<1500). Check the delay.

Using this command we are not transcoding the incoming packets, resize and relay.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i had no access to the internet. It just didn't work. FPS is as the same as before. In the meantime, as the time goes on the delay becomes worse than the beginning. Is there any relation between analyzeduration and probesize with the output?

Comment: Please check what fps the frames are captured in GoPro side. Check you internet speed/ wifi speed and your processing speed on the Android device/app.(delay may increase due to multiple factors) ? Also would request you to check the behavior on any PC side. What resolution and fps are you capturing on GoPro side?

Comment: Gopro is set to provide 60 FPS for FHD. I can run the code on the PC with no problem and the output maintains the FPS constantly. As we directly connect to the GoPro through the WIFI, I've no idea about any other factor involved in this process (and how to check the processing speed on Android)

Comment: you can check the cpu usage : adb shell top . check the logs of ffmpeg to see if multiple frames are getting dropped.